# Gnu Make: how to handle sub-projects

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

```
ProjFolder
 \ 
  Subfolder
    sources.cpp
    makefile
makefile
```

`Subfolder` is supposed to be a separate external repo, pulled in when checking out the project. When I call `make all` to the top-level makefile, the following recipes get executed:

```
all:  $(NAME).elf $(NAME).s19 $(NAME).hex

$(NAME).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(LDSCRIPT) Subfolder/lib.a
    make -C CppAudioPeriphs all
    @ echo "...linking"
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) Subfolder/lib.a $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

As you can see, if the final product of `Subfolder` - the file `lib.a` is changed, the `Subfolder` makefile gets called in order to remake it, and then all product get linked into the final flash image.

The problem is the order. *I want to always first call the sub-makefile.* It knows when and how to remake `lib.a`. And THEN check if `lib.a` is modified to determine if to remake $(NAME).elf.

---

Here is one solution.

```
.PHONY all $(NAME).elf
```

This just instructs `make` to remake $(NAME).elf no matter what. I have used this solution in the past for tiny projects, but for the current one it is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by MadScientist (and who better) I missed the obvious solution to this problem.

The solution is to `FORCE` the `Subfolder/lib.a` target to always be attempted. And as long as the `Subfolder` makefile only updates `lib.a` when something has changed the rest will fall out correctly.

So you want the following for your `Subfolder/lib.a` target. The rest can stay as-is. The trick here, as indicated before, is that you can force make to run the `Subfolder/lib.a` target itself but if the timestamp on `Subfolder/lib.a` the **file** doesn't change then things that list `Subfolder/lib.a` as a prerequisite will not need to be rebuilt.

```
FORCE: ;

Subfolder/lib.a: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D) target-to-build-lib.a*
```

Comment: Why bother with the "if .. -q ..."?  If the answer to the question is "run the real make", you should just run it always... the result will be the same and it will be a lot faster to only run make once instead of twice.

Comment: @MadScientist To get the "did it update" information. It could be avoided by either the manual timestamp checking or by leaving the original target with a prerequisite on `Subfolder/lib.a` and trusting that make will detect that correctly (but I don't know that that's actually a valid thing to count on, racing when make checks the timestamp, etc.).  But true, I wasn't thinking about the sub-make being slow. If it isn't very fast the manual timestamp checking is going to win by a mile every time.

Comment: Actually I don't understand the problem.  Why not just have the top makefile depend on Subfolder/lib.a directly, and use a FORCE rule to ensure it's tried?  The submake won't change the timestamp on the library if it's up to date so the top make won't rebuild.

Comment: @MadScientist Because I didn't think of that for some reason. =) That is clearly the better answer (and I do that at work in a number of places).

Comment: E.g., in the top make list "Subfolder/lib.a" as a prereq for $(NAME).elf, then create a rule `Subfolder/lib.a: FORCE` with a recipe of invoking the sub-make.

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting your stuff in a subfolder also (e.g. Mystuff) with its own makefile. Then you can write a top-level makefile along the lines of

```
all: Mystuff
Mystuff: Subfolder

Subfolder Mystuff:
    ${MAKE} -C $@
```

But then, [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) :)

Comment: The URL is not working, here's the copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20240211093441/https://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Comment: It worked on my machine :)